# What is the location of Overview page when VS2019 Project is created

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

As an example, when I create a `Windows application packaging` in `VS2019`, I get the following `Overview` page with important relevant links. If I want to look at those links at later time, I can't find that page. **Question**: What is the location of this page on Windows 10?

[image]

When I right click on the tab of the above page, I get the following dropdown.

[image]

And when I copy the full path of the page from this dropdown, the path shown is `AppCapabilities..\WapProj4WpfNET5Tile\WapProj4WpfNET5Tile.wapproj` where `WapProj4WpfNET5Tile` is the name of my packaging project. But I don't know where exactly that path is. Moreover, on this dropdown when I click on `Open Containing Folder`, I get the following message. I am an admin and the only user on my windows 10 pro laptop.

[image]

**UPDATE** - Dated May 20, 2021

As per the `title` of the question, the question is related to `any` project in `VS2019` and not specific to only Packaging project. However, I just observed that, for a packaging project you can get back the  `Overview page` as follows:

1. Open the `.wapproj` file (either by using `Edit project file` or by double clicking the Packaging Project file)
2. Use `Project-->Overview` menu on top bar as shown in image 1 below

However, as the image 2 below shows, the above procedure does not show the menu `Project-->Overview` if you open the `.csproj` file of any none-packaging project

**When `.wapproj` file is open**: You can get back the `Overview` page.

[image]

**When `.csproj` file is open**: The `Overview` page option is not there

[image]

**When any other file is open**: The `Overview` page option is not there

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring up the overview by using the Project->Overview option in Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: I tried and noticed that my `Project-->...` dropdown does not have `Overview` option. I'm using latest version `16.9.6` of `VS2019` - Community Edition. Is there way to bring `Overview` option?

Comment: Does it show up if you create a new packaging project in a blank solution?

Comment: To clarify my question further,  I just added an `UPDATE` section to my post above.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I thought when I create any project in `VS2019` it would create an `Overview`  page with related help links. But after reading your today's comments I created a `WPF .NET5` standalone project and noticed that it did not create an `Overview` page. I then created a `UWP`, `ASP.NET Core`, and Packaging Project projects - all of those created an Overview page with related links. And, I can get to those pages using your above suggestion.  Do you happen to know if `WPF`  projects display `Overview` page or not? If they do not then I suppose your response is correct - and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: There is no overview for WPF projects as far as I know.

Comment: That's what I observed, as well. I'm marking your response as an `Answer` since it worked for my other projects (thank you).